# Could this be a phishing hidden service?

Tags: onion-services, facebook

I am trying to connect to the Facebook Tor hidden service i copied and pasted it from the Tor blog post and even the Wikipedia everything loads fine however i have noticed that the design of the web page sometimes changes is this a design choice or a possible phishing page? I have also checked the clearnet version and it's the same there as well so i'm leaning towards a design choice but wanted to come hear and ask before i entered my login information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to check to see if a website is or is not a phishing attempt is the exact same way regardless of the browser.

1. Click on the information link:

[image]

2. Click on the arrow for the certificate on the right:
3. Check the certificate:

[image]

Facebook has one of the few onion services that uses trusted certificates. They are still expensive and hard to get. If the onion service does not, the it is up to you to check to see if the url is correct from a known good source. Hopefully a service like Let's Encrypt will cover onion services in the future.

Comment: Thank you it's a match so is the change a design choice?

Comment: No idea, I refuse to use facebook.

Comment: I don't really use it very much i am working on a project that requires it and wanted to know if it was a phshing site before entering my login everything matches up so must be a design choice